ImportError: cannot import name 'CuDNNLSTM' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers'
I am learning Machine Learning and AI and looking at a code written about 2-3 years back.  Here is part of the code where I a facing issue:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import time
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM,Dropout,Dense,Input,add

When I run using the above code I get the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'CuDNNLSTM' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers'

When I searched for solution I got the following suggestion:
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM

So I added the above line and removed CuDNNLSTM from the previous import line.  Now I get his error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat.v1.keras'

Can I get help to solve the above issue?
Here is the extract of the code where CuDNNLSTM is used.
    inputs = Input(shape=(240,1))
    x = CuDNNLSTM(25,return_sequences=False)(inputs)
    x = Dropout(0.1)(x)


Maybe you should simply replace CuDNNLSTM to LSTM. The CuDNNLSTM has been deprecated.
According to this answer, you can no longer specify CuDNNLSTM. Instead, it will be used automatically when certian conditions are met.
